Use data posted to a Google Cloud Run Function
Goal: When a cell is edited in a Google Sheet, send the row to a Node.js Google Cloud Run Function to be processed as a variable in the code.
In my apps script on the Google Sheet, I can successfully send POST data to the function (at least, there are no errors returned). I don't know how to handle the data after it's sent to the function. Specifically, how do I put that data into a variable for use in the function? The function is Node.js.
Code that sends the data from the Sheet to the function:
const url = "<my function URL>";
const string = row
const params = {
  method: "post",
  contentType: "application/json",
  payload: string,
};
const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
console.log(res.getContentText());

row will be an array of cell values in a row:
[
  "cellA1contents",
  "cellA2contents",
  "cellA3contents"
]

Current code of the function (default):
const functions = require('@google-cloud/functions-framework');

functions.http('helloHttp', (req, res) => {
  res.send(`Hello ${req.query.name || req.body.name || 'World'}!`);
});

When I look at the current function logs, the event is logged as error free, parameters are listed, but my payload data is not visible.
Desired future code of the function will have a variable that has the POST body (row). The code will then parse it to create an HTML table and send the HTML to a CMS.
I am not a programmer or cloud engineer - I just try to automate projects in my non-engineering role - thank you kindly for any patience and for any answers!

You're showing three variables, but nothing there actually invokes the function.  Also it's not clear what row is or how you expect it to show up in the function.  It would also be helpful if you show the code of the function so we can see what you're doing to try to observe the payload (as that might be incorrect as well).  Please edit the code to be complete, so that anyone can copy and run it for themselves.

According to the documentation for fetch, params.payload should be an object, not an array.  You need to give the payload at least one name/value pair, and use that specific name in the function.  I think you'll make debugging this easier on yourself if you start with some very simple hard-coded data, make it work like that first, then add in some variables later.  Also consider logging something within your function so you know exactly what your request variable contains before using it.

In addition to what Doug said, while payload can be a string(strings are objects, just like arrays), you should stringify the payload to a string: payload: JSON.stringify(row), for it to work as you expect.
